# Pass values to variables in script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

**`Goal:`**

1. get all the policy names in account
2. get the policy version for each of the above policies
3. pass these as variables to a second cli command

*What i have so far:*

```
#!/bin/bash

policy=$(aws iam list-policies | jq -r '.Policies[] | {name:.PolicyName,arn:.Arn,version:.DefaultVersionId}' | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]")

for key in $policy; do
    eval ${key}
    aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn ${arn} --version-id ${version}
done
```

the script will run but will constantly return an error because i think there is a mismatch in the values being used.

`Error:`

```
An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetPolicyVersion operation: 
Policy arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:policy/service-role/SOME_POLICY_NAME version v2 
does not exist or is not attachable.
```

Comment: have you tried adding `set -x` (turn on debug output) for your script? before the `policy=` line

Comment: This happens because your `${key}` will be version in one iteration of the loop, in the next one it will be arn, and so on, instead of iterating over pairs.

Comment: You are correct about this part of the logic. My bash foo is terrible. This is actually true @Marcin I would like each "object" to include `{name,arn,version}`. Going to try and fix this and post a solution once i find it. If it was not bash i think this would have been easier, but already here so might as well flex my brain a little and make it do some work.

Comment: Looks like the : in your arn variables are the issue. Use aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$arn" --version-id "$version"

Comment: i solved this and will post the solution soon.

Comment: @codelinx How soon is soon? It's been 7 months already

Comment: I have to search. I need the to find the script :) and i forgot about stackoverflow cause i was not logged in when i visited here so i could not see the message badge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming neither of your 3 property values contains any whitespace, the solution becomes almost trivial (eliminating all the issues that `eval` of untrusted data brings):

```
#!/bin/sh

aws iam list-policies |
  jq -r '.Policies[] | "\(.PolicyName) \(.Arn) \(.DefaultVersionId)"' |
  while read -r name arn version rest; do
    aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$arn" --version-id "$version"
  done
```

- The jq filter will print all name, arn, version of one policy per line
- `while read -r name arn version rest` will assign each word in a line to the variable (if there are more than 3 words, all remaining words go into "rest")
- The loopy body then calls the second command with the variable values

(Note that you never used "name" in your question, so it could be removed from jq and read. Secondly note, that `jq` needs only be invoked once).

Please let us know if whitespace must be support as part of the values.